# Unable to convert JSON string from API call into Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

Good morning! I'm still learning my way around REST API calls and generally processing HTTP requests, so please provide any feedback :)

I'm trying to make a GET call to a web service, which should return a JSON string that's a set of information, which is supposed to be a SQL record returned in a sort of dictionary-like manner.

However, I am having several hiccups and don't know if I'm approach the resolution correctly:

1. Call web service. Define it as a 'GET' call.
2. Process the response and read it using a StreamReader.
3. Using the NewtonSoft JSON method, deserialize the response into a dictionary format. <-- Currently stuck here.
4. Use dictionary to my liking.

   ```
   // Call the Web Service
                   string url = "{URL HERE}"; 

                   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                   request.Method = "GET";
                   request.ContentType = "application/json";
                   request.ContentLength = 0;
                       //Dictionary<string, string> dataList = null;

                   try
                   {
                       WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                       Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                       StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                       var json = reader.ReadToEnd();

                       //Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

                       var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>>>(json);
                       var dataDictionary = data.ToDictionary(
                            x => x.Key,
                            x => x.Value.ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Value));

                       //dataList = (Dictionary<string, string>) dataDictionary;

                       var test = dataDictionary["Key"];
   ```

What the JSON string from the call sort of looks like:

- "[{\"Number\":4,\"FieldABC\":\"ABC\"}]"

Other solutions I have tried:

1. Using the data type **Dictionary** instead.
2. Various other method calls, like the ones commented out in the code.
3. Another SO post suggested the ToDictionary() call.

Errors I have run into:

- {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"}  System.Exception {System.ArgumentNullException}
- Cannot convert JSON string to JSON object.

Am I misunderstanding how to process the response from the HTTP request? Or am I confusing / misusing data types? Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

Update: With all the answers below, the solution ended up being a combination of all of the comments! First, I used json2csharp.com to create the object. Then, using the updated HTTP calls recommended below, I deserialized the JSON into a type Lists so that I got a list of length 1 that I could access my information from. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Try doing, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>` instead, then you can walk the JSON tree.

Comment: First, find out what the JSON actually looks like. Create a class with exactly the same properties and make them strings first, because that will never fail. 
Then use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YourClass>>(responseString);` to create a list of your objects from the json-string your received. 
The problem with using a `Dictionary` is that is consists of `KeyValue`-pairs where the keys have to be unique in that `Dictionary`. If that is not the case the conversion will fail.

Comment: @Callum, I tried changing the code to: var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);, and received the error 'Unable to case object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'. Are there prior steps needed to 'walk the JSON tree' (Sorry, I am afraid I am unfamiliar with the terminology).

Comment: Well then change `JObject` to `JArray` ....

Comment: @Bunnynut The JSON string resembles "[{\"Number\":4,\"FieldABC\":\"ABC\"}]" with more fields. The example in the post was simplified for reading purposes. Is there another JSON object I am missing? Or should I be converting that string to something else?

Comment: For that example JSON string try Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
That JSON structure isn't compatible with the structure of List<KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when I use `http://json2csharp.com/` for example to use your JSON, I would get:

```
public class ClassName
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string FieldABC { get; set; }
}
```

Use `HttpClient`, that makes it easier:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(progressUrl);
    var yourObject == JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassName>(await response .Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

Continue with the rest...

You can also use [HttpClientExtensions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions(v=vs.118).aspx).

Cheers!

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone for their help! All of these comments have really taught me a lot about JSON and other coding practices. Unfortunately, I couldn't mark everything or upvote everything, but the link to json2csharp really helped with my large object. I'll update my post :)

Comment: @Roelant some minor fixes: `var yourObject ==` should be `var yourObject =` and `response .Content` (space) should be `response.Content`

Answer (score 0):

First make a POCO which exactly matches the response string. Something like this:

```
public class MyResponseObject {

    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string FieldABC { get; set; }

    // other properties here
}
```

Assuming you are sent an array of these objects as `[{\"Number\":4,\"FieldABC\":\"ABC\"}]` suggests then you can deserialize it using

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyResponseObject>>(json);
```

If it is a more complicated object then you can include additional nested objects in your principal object:

```
public class MyNestedObject {

    public string NestedName { get; set; }

    public bool IsEnabled { get;  set; }

}


public class MyResponseObject {

    public List<MyNestedObject> NestedObjects { get; set; }

}
```

Once you have a `List<MyResponseObject>` you may find you don't need a dictionary at all, or if you do you can take advantage of the many Linq Enumerable methods without worrying about JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Use HttpClient instead of HttpWebRequest, as follows:

```
        using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Dictionary<string, string> ValueList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);
        }
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, code-only answers are frowned upon.  Please also provide an explanation to OP to explain your answer.  [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)